# Automatically update Free Pascal program at program startup, without admin prompt

Tags: windows, nsis, freepascal

Many Windows programs are able to run an update when they start, without an admin prompt.  Similarly, my program needs to update itself, without any user input.  Any user who logs in needs to be able to use the program.

My program can already find new updates, download them, and run them, but the NSIS installer/updater requires admin rights.

What would I need to do to implement this using Free Pascal and NSIS, short of giving all users access to the installation directory?

Comment: Install a service to do the update. Or install to an directory which standard user can write.

Comment: @David What do you mean by a "service", exactly?  Could you give me an example?

Comment: If you dont know what a service is you should not write one for security reasons. Take the second option.

Comment: Web search for windows service. But if you don't know what one is then likely you aren't ready to tackle this task.

Comment: If you're asking if you can bypass the UAC prompt, then no, you can't. This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application that important that you need to do this? How often do you actually plan to push out updates?

Most applications can probably get away with just elevating with UAC each time it needs to install a update.

If you absolutely feel that you need to "bypass UAC" then you can do what Firefox does; install a [NT Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service). You don't start this service in the installer but you must call `GetNamedSecurityInfo`+[`SetNamedSecurityInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579(v=vs.85).aspx) so you can add SERVICE_START access for the Everyone group to the ACL. Your application running as a normal user can then start this service when there is an update and the service does the updating.

From a security standpoint there are some dangers here because the service runs with full access to the system so you must make sure that your updates are signed so it does not become an easy to use backdoor if someone is able to pull off a man in the middle attack.

I personally think that you should consider doing per-user installations if your program is not too big...